# Magento1 Get Simple Product

Tags: magento-1.9, product-type

I have created a custom product level attribute in magento now I want that attribute in my cart so I created the column in quote item table now I need the value of that attribute, while adding products into cart. I am facing issue when I add configurable product in cart.

**This is my code**

```
public function salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute($observer)
{
    $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $quoteItem->setCustomAttribute($product->getCustomAttribute());
}
```

It returns me configurable attribute value not the child products or simple products attribute value

Comment: How did you create the column in quote_item table? Directly in the database or through any extension?

Comment: using script sss

Comment: Can you update what you have tried and how you have added the attribute? Also do you want to update the same to order_item as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get child products of current configurable product.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(3); // configurable product Id
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                ->getUsedProducts(null,$product);

foreach($childProducts as $child) {
print_r($child->getName());  // You can use any of the magic get functions on this object to get the value
```

**UPDATE :**

```
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                ->getChildrenIds(3);
}
```

Comment: but it will increse the add time ?

Comment: because i have exetnsion which add multiple product at a time

Comment: Check my edit .